# How do I add AdMob ads in my Flash AS3 app?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, admob, ads

Below are the steps I've taken:

1) I downloaded Admob Ane (admob_all_in_one6.6.7.ane) from http://code.google.com/p/flash-air-admob-ane-for-ios-and-android.

2) I added this native extension to my Flash CS6 project via Advanced ActionScript 3 settings -> Library path tab.

3) I set my Flash target to the Air 4.0.01390 for Android.

4) I wrote a small class to initialize the ads:

```
package
{
  import flash.display.Sprite;

import so.cuo.platform.admob.Admob;
import so.cuo.platform.admob.AdmobEvent;

public class Interstitial extends Sprite
{
    var admob:Admob= Admob.getInstance();

            public function Interstitial()
    {
       super();
            }

            public function displayAdd():void
            {
       if(admob.supportDevice)
               {
                    // i have replaced setKeys with my admob ad unit id "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx"
            admob.setKeys("a152834c8723912"); 

                      admob.addEventListener(AdmobEvent.onInterstitialReceive,onAdReceived);
            admob.cacheInterstitial();
       }
    }

    protected function onAdReceived(event:AdmobEvent):void
    {
        if(event.type==AdmobEvent.onInterstitialReceive){
            admob.showInterstitial();
        }
    }
}
```

5) In my main.as class I am calling the displayadd() method like this...

```
var showAdd:Interstitial = new Interstitial();
showAdd.displayAdd();
```

6) I have added this code to myappname-app.xml

```
<android>
    <manifestAdditions>
       <![CDATA[<manifest>
           <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
           <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
              <application>
         <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/> 
         </application>
       </manifest>]]>
    </manifestAdditions>
</android>

<extensions>
    <extensionID>so.cuo.platform.admob</extensionID>
 </extensions>
```

7) I published the app to my new Samsung that uses Android version 4.2.2.

No ads are being displayed. My app just crashes and deactivates when I call:

```
var showAdd:Interstitial = new Interstitial();
showAdd.displayAdd();
```

Did I miss anything ?

Comment: How did you download the ANE? There is no download option on the link you provided. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the following will help you out at all, but I managed to follow it and add AdMob ads to a banner in my game:

[How to setup AdMob with a libgdx app](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AdMobInLibgdx)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

it seems no error,try  update flash cs6 to flash cc,air sdk to 14,and download the last version admob ane.maybe it is caused by air 4 not support by android 4.0 sdk.